# MTM 2010-Running Test Case Can't see excepted result,and got html tags in the steps

Tags: tfs, testcase, microsoft-test-manager

i am using Microsoft Test Manager 2010 and TFS 2012,
The problem started when the company changed to tfs 2012 from 2010,
we have installed SP1 and the GDR Update for tfs 2012.

First Part Of the problem
-when you try to edit one of the steps 2 html tag are added to the text Step Text.

Second Part Of The Problem,
-when you try to run the test case you can't see the excepted result.

can you help me to fix it?
(i have tried unistall and reinstall without success)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

apperntally some files remain thier after the uninstall , so after the uninstall i manualy removed the remaining files, and reinstall and error gone.